# Additional Nodes Not Being Displayed In Node-Red (Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-8, node-red

and thanks for your time.

I'm just beginning to get started with Node-Red and am having trouble adding new nodes to the environment. My node-red instance has been installed according to the following instructions:

1. Extract node-red-0.11.1.zip to desired location
2. Navigate to extracted directory (so you can see bin directory and red.js file and settings.js file)
3. Open node js command prompt or windows cmd with admin rights in same folder (containing bin, settings.js and red.js)
4. Execute: `npm install --production`
5. Once npm install is complete, open settings.js for the current project
6. Set the desired port for this installation to deploy on on line 23 of settings.js
   Only one instance of node red can be run on an individual port at any given time. That one instance can utilise multiple sheets, however.
7. Set name of the flows file (which is saved when "Deploy" is hit) to desired name on line 47 of settings.js
8. Set user directory path to this installation's project directory (the one containing bin, settings.js and red.js) on line 55 of settings.js
   This keeps this installation's flows, settings etc. seperate from those of other node-red installations/projects.
   Leaving it as the default setting will result in the flows being overwritten if another default installation deploys flows.
9. In the same command-prompt window (node red or Windows), use the node red.js command to run this instance.
   In the dialogue shown, comfirm location of the flows and settings file (displayed in the print-out given at startup).

Now, the above all works fine and I can create flows, see them working. When I try to install additional nodes (for example, [ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping)), I navigate to the folder described above (containing red.js, the settings files etc.) and - in the node js terminal - run the command `npm install ping` which results in:
`ping@0.1.10 node_modules\ping
└── q@1.4.1`
being output to the terminal window. If I navigate to the node-modules folder, I can see the ping package successfully installed. When I then start the node-red service with `node red.js -v`, however, I am unable to find the new node in the 
interface.

The output of the `node red.js -v` command is as follows:

```
`Welcome to Node-RED
18 Nov 10:05:56 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.11.1
18 Nov 10:05:56 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.10.32
18 Nov 10:05:56 - [info] Loading palette nodes
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [warn] [tail] Not currently supported on Windows.
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] Settings file  : c:\Users\Me\workspace_nodeRed\NodeRe
dTuts\node-red-0.11.1\settings.js
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] User directory : C:/Users/Me/workspace_nodeRed/NodeRe
dTuts/node-red-0.11.1
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] Flows file : c:\Users\Me\workspace_nodeRed\NodeRedTut
s\node-red-0.11.1\flows.json
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1854/
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] Starting flows
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] [inject:fd665561.0299a8] repeat = 300000
18 Nov 10:05:57 - [info] Started flows`
```

Edit: Word in opening line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is not a Node-RED node it is just a normal nodejs node, so Node-RED isn't going to know what to do with it.

The Node-RED ping node is called `node-red-node-ping` so you would need to run the following to install it.

```
npm install node-red-node-ping
```

Comment: D'oh. Well, I feel stupid! Thank you very much for your swift response.... Installing node-red-node-ping worked as expected.